# There are many threads reserved while golang application running

Tags: multithreading, go, goroutine

The golang application is a tool that receives file by invoking a c library, saves it to disk and report the transfer state to monitor service with http protocol.

After a few transferring, I found there are about 70+ threads existed with a few goroutines.

I check the c and go source code, there are no thread or goroutine leak found.
I use "dlv" to debug the application, here is the stack of one of the such threads:

```
(dlv) bt
0  0x000000000046df03 in runtime.futex
   at /home/vagrant/resource/go/src/runtime/sys_linux_amd64.s:388
1  0x0000000000437e92 in runtime.futexsleep
   at /home/vagrant/resource/go/src/runtime/os_linux.go:45
2  0x000000000041e042 in runtime.notesleep
   at /home/vagrant/resource/go/src/runtime/lock_futex.go:145
3  0x000000000044036d in runtime.stopm
   at /home/vagrant/resource/go/src/runtime/proc.go:1594
4  0x0000000000441178 in runtime.findrunnable
   at /home/vagrant/resource/go/src/runtime/proc.go:2021
5  0x0000000000441cec in runtime.schedule
   at /home/vagrant/resource/go/src/runtime/proc.go:2120
6  0x0000000000442063 in runtime.park_m
   at /home/vagrant/resource/go/src/runtime/proc.go:2183
7  0x0000000000469f1b in runtime.mcall
   at /home/vagrant/resource/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:240
```

I don't know where these threads come from or may be threads pool of golang runtime?

Could any one look at this, thank you very much!

Comment: Please show code... You may use http://play.golang.org

Comment: sorry, it is company's project. I can't post code here. I read the source code of the stack mentioned above, it seems that the sleeping logic is ok, scheduler put the "m" to sleep and wait for next waking up. but everytime scheduler will start a new "m" to run the task, so the previous "m" won't be waked up, which costs threads little by little.

Answer (score 3):

#### The problem

> The golang application is a tool that receives file by invoking a c
>   library, saves it to disk and report the transfer state to monitor
>   service with http protocol.
>
> After a few transferring, I found there are about 70+ threads existed
>   with a few goroutines.

#### The cause

Each call to C (via `cgo`, or `syscall` on Windows etc) is no really
different from performing an OS system call as long as the Go scheduler
is concerned.

What happens is this:

1. When a goroutine is being executed, it runs on an OS thread
   (this is sort of obvious, I fathom).
2. When it performs a syscall or calls C, that goroutine blocks
   (stops executing Go code).
3. The Go runtime scheduler watches after the goroutines which got blocked
   and after at east a single "scheduler tick" (which currently — in
   Go 1.8 and 1.9 — is 20 µs) passes, and the goroutine is still blocked,
   and there are other runnable goroutines,
   the scheduler *creates another OS thread* to make other goroutines
   continue execution.

This behaviour might appear to be counter-intuitive at first
but without it, on, say, a two-CPU machine, you would need to just call
two syscalls (such as reading or writing a file) in parallel from
any two goroutines to block the rest of the active goroutines
from doing their work.
In other words, the scheduler tries to keep up with the Go's promise
of always having up to `GOMAXPROCS` goroutines running
if there are goroutines which want to run, and `GOMAXPROCS`
is set to the number of CPUs (cores) of the machine.

So, what happens is that if you have a reasonably high churn of C calls which complete slower than that single scheduler tick, you'll have growing pool
of allocated OS threads.

Note that this is not bad in itself: sure, you'll be allocating resources
(on a typical commodity OS each thread has some 8 MiB of stack allocated
plus some bookkeeping data structures internal to the OS) but they are
not wasted: these threads will get reused as soon as they will be needed.
Say, your next burst of such C calls will reuse the allocated threads.

#### The solution

Still, if you'd like to prevent that from happening, the common approach
is to reasonably serialize your C calls.

A typical approach to this is to have a single "worker" goroutine
which receives "tasks" — in the form of values of some type, usually
a custom type created by you — over a channel and sends the results of
their execution over another channel.

The input channel may be buffered — effectively turning it into a queue.

If you'd still want to parallelize that work, you can have a pool of
worker goroutines — all reading the single input channel and writing to
the single output channel.

But note that if those C calls spend most of their time doing disk I/O
*and* the files they read/write are located on the filesystem which
is backed by a *single* medium, you usually won't gain much with
parallelizing unless that medium is blazingly fast — such as SSD or
in-memory (RAM) disk.

So consider all the options and think through your design.